# About a variation of the primitive root idea.

Tags: definition, congruences, primitive-roots

Let $n $ be called a *half* primitive root mod ($m$) if $n^{\phi(m)/2} = 1$ mod($m$) and for any $t $ with $1 < t < \phi(m)/2$, $m$ does not divide $(n^t - 1)$. So the order of $n$ mod($m$) is $\phi(m)/2$. Also $n, n^2 , n^3 , .., n^{(p-1)/2}$ are all distinct and they are all the quadratic residues mod($m$) in some order. All integers that are the products of at least two distinct prime divisors have a half primitive root , is this true?

Comment: What is $p$? Presumably an odd prime, but how related to the problem?

Comment: How are $p$ and $m$ related? Would you rather want to define a half-primitive root modulo $m$ to be an integer $n$ with order $\phi(m)/2$? When $m = p$ is a prime, this reduces to your definition.

Comment: Do you want product of distinct primes or having at least $2$ distinct prime divisors? If the latter, then $24$ is a counterexample.

Comment: The order of 2 mod(45) is 12 which = ('phi'(45)/2) so 2 would be a half primitive root mod(45) (I think). Actually if 2 is a quadratic residue mod(m) and 2^('phi'(m)/4 -1) < m (m is a composite number and not a prime power) and 2^('phi'(m)/4) is not congruent to 1 mod(m) then 2 is a half primitive root mod(m).

Comment: So 2 is a half primitive root mod(45) (I think). So the one counterexample Andre Nicholas gives does disprove the hypothesis for all integers but my example shows it works for some integers..